# How to Compare two dates in PowerShell & get difference in minutes

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to compare LastWriteTime of a file and compare it to the current time. if the difference is greater then 45 minutes then I need to get a email alert.

Here is what I got so far.

```
$StartDate=(GET-DATE)

$EndDate=[datetime]”01/01/2014 00:00”

NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate
```

In code above I need to replace `$EndDate` with `Get-Item C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\file.html | select LastWriteTime`

I need to compare the LastWriteTime of file.html with current time.

Please help me store 
`Get-Item C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\file.html | select LastWriteTime` into `$EndDate`

so I can do the compare.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
if (((Get-Date) - (Get-ChildItem file.html).LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes -gt 45) {
 Write-Host "Old file"
}
```

Just to get the date into a variable would be:

```
$EndDate = (Get-Item C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\file.html).LastWriteTime
```

or

```
$EndDate = Get-Item C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\file.html |
    select -expandproperty LastWriteTime
```

The `select -expandproperty` syntax is needed on old versions of Powershell (prior to 3.0) when you might be accessing a property on multiple objects. I don't think it is needed even on Powershell 2 if there is only a single object.

Comment: Awesome Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation. Just a question for the if state code, if the statement is false meaning file.html is not old and it was updated with in 45 minutes then code doesn't do anything right?